# Why when updating an existing property value with spread operator the value gets added in the array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object

I have a state which contains an array of objects:

```
const initialState=[{a:1},{b:2},{c:{d:3}}]

const [state,setState]=useState(initialState)
```

I want to change the value of b to 5 in my event handler:

```
function changeBToFive() {
    setState((state) => [
      ...state,
      (state[1].b = 5),
    ]);
  }
```

And the result of the new state is:

```
[{a:1},{b:5},{c:{d:3}},5]
```

So it is updating the value of "b" correctly. But it is adding the value 5 at the end.

Why is that??

Thank you.

Comment: Because your code explicitly asks to add an additional element.

Comment: So how should I do to only update the value without adding it?

Comment: Update the value before doing the spread operation.

Answer (score 1):

It is because `(state[1].b = 5)` returns `5`, which becomes the last element in the array you are creating. Instead, change the value first and then use `setState`.

```
function changeBToFive() {
    setState((state) => {
        state[1].b = 5;
        return [...state];
     });
}
```

Comment: Is this not mutating the state?

Comment: Well then create the new state array, check for an object with a `"b"` property, and if there isn't one, add it, and then call `setState()`.

Comment: Thank you @iota! So it means that if I set initial state as an object instead of array as: `const initialState= {a:1,b:2,c:{d:3}}`. Then I can use the syntax as `{..state," nested value to change"}`. And the function would be: `function changeBToFive() {
  setState((nestedObject) =>
      return { ...state, b: 5 };
    });
  }`   So I can merge an updated nested state value with current state with this syntax in objects but if I use this syntax in arrays, then it adds a new value at the end of the array right?

Comment: @pepinillo6969 Yes.